# Where to store abbreviations for long class names in Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I constantly need to use long class name like

```
SomeReallyLongModuleName::AnotherLongModuleName::YetAnotherLongClassName
```

in the project. I want to access this class by something like `YALCN`. Where it's the best to keep definition like

```
YALCN = SomeReallyLongModuleName::AnotherLongModuleName::YetAnotherLongClassName
```

And is it a common practice, or people constantly use fully-qualified long name?

Answer (score 3):

If this is only for Rails console usage, I'd put them into `/lib/aliases.rb` or somewhere similar and `require` the file when needed.

Answer (score 2):

You could make "local" aliases. Something like this:

```
class Another
  YALCN = SomeReallyLongModuleName::AnotherLongModuleName::YetAnotherLongClassName

  def do_something
    YALCN.new # or whatever
  end
end
```

Answer (score 1):

To avoid problems with autoloading, I'd keep the short constants in the same place they're used.

> And is it a common practice, or people constantly use fully-qualified long name?

I haven't seen this too often.

Comment: They are used all over the project, because they are the model class names.
And it's so tiresome to constantly use full name in the `rails console`.
So I think about defining the abbreviations in the global scope.
Just not sure where it's best to keep those definitions.
Probably in some file `abbreviations.rb` in the `model` folder or something.

Comment: You could try to reference them in initializers or after loading of the whole app. It may interfere with code reloading though...

Comment: Well, initiailizsers might be a good choice. Tnanks for suggestion. Are they supposed to be used for things like that, and not only for configuring some project-wide components?

Comment: They can be, but I haven't tested that. I'm afraind it'll break reloading.

Comment: One problem with referencing classes in an initializer is that they will be loaded instead of lazy loading them when they are actually used. You could get around that by using strings and using `.constantize` when you actually need to use them. Otherwise Sergio Tulentsevs answer is generally better than just defining a bunch of what is essentially glorified globals.